# Google Plus Api people information

Tags: php, google-plus, social-networking

i'm building a PHP site where i have to sync the users social data, and he's social connections data.
Using GoolePlus API, it gives me the users connections (friends) list and i have to make a profile request for each person to get his profile info.
Is there any way of getting the list of people with thei information in 1 request?
(somethin like linkedin request for connections)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [people.list](https://developers.google.com/+/api/latest/people/list) response includes basic profile info (name, ID, URL, image). If you need more profile details you will have to call [people.get](https://developers.google.com/+/api/latest/people/get). You can however [batch requests](https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/php/guide/batch) where you batch say 50 people.get requests together, send it to Google where Google unspools the requests and performs them individually. The results are then returned to you all at the same time.